# "Radial" strongly singular function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose you rotate the graph of Lebesgue's strongly singular function (strictly increasing, zero derivative almost everywhere on $[0,1]$) around the $y$-axis. What is the surface measure of the resulting surface by revolution?

Comment: What is the integral of Lebesgue's function, for starters?

Comment: Perhaps my question was misleading. The length of the graph of any continuous, strictly increasing, strongly singular function from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$ is $2$. Is there an analogous, conceptual way of finding the surface measure in question?